# xpath запрос с условием

Tags: xpath

```
<div class='table-wrap'>
<table class='dashTable'><tbody>
<tr>
<td class='dashBoard'><b>ID</b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'><b>Name</b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'><b>TEP</b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'><b>Status</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='dashBoard'>001</td>
<td class='dashBoard'>Liam</td>
<td class='dashBoard'><font color="#00875a"><b>2-Nov-2022 1 PM CET</b> </font></td>
<td class='dashBoard'> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='dashBoard'>002</td>
<td class='dashBoard'> <b><font color="#00875a">Noah</font></b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'>  <b><font color="#00875a">2-Nov-2022 1 PM CET</font></b> </td>
<td class='dashBoard'> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='dashBoard'>003</td>
<td class='dashBoard'> <b><font color="#00875a">James</font></b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'><font color="#00875a"><b>2-Nov-2022 1 PM CET</b> </font></td>
<td class='dashBoard'> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class='dashBoard'>004</td>
<td class='dashBoard'>Lucas<br/>
 <del>Lauren</del><br/>
 <b><font color="#00875a">Lucie</font></b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'>   <b><font color="#00875a">2-Nov-2022 6 PM JST</font></b></td>
<td class='dashBoard'> </td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

Возможно ли написать запрос, с помощью которого из каждого `td[2]` я смогу выбрать только элемент `b[font]`, но в случае если `td[2]` не имеет `b[font]`, то выбрать целый атрибут `td[2]` со всеми его элементами?

Остановился на этом, запрос находит только `b[font]`, но пропускает `td` в случае если нету дочерних элементов:

```
//div[@class="table-wrap"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/b[font]
```

Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath с условием `or`:

```
//div[@class="table-wrap"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2][b[font]]/b[font] | //div[@class="table-wrap"]/table/tbody/tr/td[2][not(b[font])]
```

Comment: Работает отлично, спасибо

Comment: вторая часть выдала и <td class='dashBoard'><b>Name</b></td>  и <td class='dashBoard'>Liam</td>

Answer (score 0):

проверялось на http://xpather.com/

```
//td[2]/b[not(contains(@id, 'b'))]/font/text()
```

для элементов, включающих <b>

```
//td[2][not(child::b)]/text()
```

для элементов, не включающих <b>

прим., возможно text() лучше удалить.